# Importing BeautifulSoup from a (relative) parent folder, and a html parser alongside it

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, lxml

Here is my folder tree:

```
script/
    main.py
    dependencies/
        bs4/
            ...
        requests/
            ...
```

Here is how I am importing the modules from `main.py`:

```
import dependencies.requests as requests
import dependencies.bs4 as bs4
```

The script seems to work just fine, but I can't figure out how to add a html parser into `dependencies\` to work alongside BeautifulSoup. So currently when in `main.py` I make the following GET request:

```
response = requests.get(url)
```

And then attempt to parse it:

```
parsed_html = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
```

Then I get the following exception:

```
File "C:\Users\usr\Desktop\script\dependencies\bs4\__init__.py", line 165, in __init__
% ",".join(features))

dependencies.bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Also, the default `"html.parser"` throws the same exception.

Comment: `"html.parser"` should work automatically, but `lxml` needs to be installed, have you `pip install lxml`?

Comment: Yup, `lxml` is installed. Parsing works totally fine with both `lxml` and `"html.parser"`, as long as I don't shove `bs4` into the `dependencies/` folder. If I have `bs4` in the same folder as `main.py` and do `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup` then it works perfectly, but I'd really like to put it in the `dependencies/` folder to keep everything neat and organized.

Comment: Oh ok, so `bs4` is not installed on your system, rather you've got the `bs4` source extracted into `dependencies/bs4`? same with `requests`?

Comment: I have both parser installed correctly, but for the purposes of this application, we can assume that to be true, yes. I just need to figure out how to make `bs4` accept `"html.parser"` or `lxml` as an external module that isn't installed through `pip`. Not quite sure what I'm supposed to pass through as an argument in `parsed_html = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.content, x)` to make it happen. For context, I'm making this application for portability reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should extend your `PYTHONPATH` to the folder where your lxml or html.parser is installed. With this, "python" will know in which specific location to search for your packages.

In either case, you are making your own structure of folders with dependencies since there are tools for this such as [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/).

Comment: Extending my `PYTHONPATH` worked great, thanks. Reference for any potential future readers: https://askubuntu.com/questions/470982/how-to-add-a-python-module-to-syspath/471168